# Can't identify sliding vinyl window part - bottom "slide" / "guide" / "rail" (image included)

Tags: windows

The bottom sliding guide of my vinyl windows looks worn and ugly, anyone knows what's that called exactly and if it's possible to find a replacement. All my searching so far turned up exactly nothing.

As you can see in the picture, the bottom "guide" pulls out easily as if it was meant to be replaceable.

I don't know what brand the windows are.

[image]

Comment: It's a North Star  window.  Their web site shows dealers in the Midwest but they don't have any links for replacement parts. Try cleaning it with some vinegar.

Comment: @JACK wow, how did you figure this out from just a picture of a corner of the window?

Comment: It's on the piece of wood on the lower left. Zoom in on the picture